# find my apple store password by keychain

Tags: macos

I get the apple store  password like this by keychain，How to decrypt this password. Thinks.

AAAABLwIAAAAAFxjqLYRCmdzLmlkbXMuaGK9AEZZwubB0nS2GASNkRZ871dwJTS3hu3btfMaI2o9jvbCYqo2oA

[image]

[image]

Comment: if that was possible then it would remove the security we all enjoy...

Answer (score 3):

It is not an encrypted password and as such it cannot be decrypted to give you your App Store password.

The value you see is a token that allows programs to authenticate directly for the App Store, so in some sense it can be thought of as a password - but it is not derived from your actual password.

Comment: think you ,  my be i sholud be get my password by others way